# Babel package name convention on npm

Tags: npm, babeljs

Babel seems to offer two sets of packages on npm. One is named with a '@' prefix and '/' separator such as [@babel/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core). The other is named without a '@' prefix and with '-' separator such as [babel-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core). Is it because they changed the naming convention since version 7 or due to another reason?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they changed the naming convention since version 7.